# Comparing functions for equality in Rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a function which takes a number as an argument, and then returns a function based on the number. Depending on many different things, it might return any of ~50 functions, and the cases for which one it should return get pretty complicated. As such, I want to build some tests to make sure the proper functions are being returned. What I have so far looks roughly like this.

```
fn pick_a_function(decider: u32) -> fn(&mut SomeStruct) {
    match decider {
        1 => add,
        2 => sub,
        _ => zero,
    }
}

fn add(x: &mut SomeStruct) {
    x.a += x.b;
}

fn sub(x: &mut SomeStruct) {
    x.a -= x.b;
}

fn zero(_x: &mut SomeStruct) {
    x.a = 0;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = SomeStruct { a: 2, b: 3 };
    pick_a_function(1)(&mut x);

    println!("2 + 3 = {}", x.a);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn picks_correct_function() {
        assert_eq!(pick_a_function(1), add);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the functions don't seem to implement the `Eq` or `PartialEq` traits, so `assert_eq!` just says that it can't compare them. What options do I have for comparing the returned function to the correct function?

Comment: You have a problem in assert_eq because of the missing Debug trait but there's no problem testing function equality (which is the comparison of the pointers). You can check `println!("{}", pick_a_function(1) == add);`. Do you use a old rustc (you might have to cast to usize if so)?

Comment: @DenysSéguret After digging into it more last night I realized that functions do implement `PartialEq`, but only if they aren't attached to a lifetime. One the arguments that they all take is a mutable struct reference, which implicitly attaches a lifetime to the functions, preventing them from being `PartialEq`. Casting the function as a usize seems to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the result instead of the function,for example:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn picks_correct_function() {
      let add_picked = pick_a_function(1);
      assert_eq!(add_picked(1,2), add(1,2));
    }
}
```

Or in more complex scenarios you can compare the inputs making a function that takes one parameter and another that takes two,try to call any of them and see if you get a compiler error.

Comment: The functions being returned don't actually return a result, they mutate a struct that they take as an argument, and initializing one of those structs is really expensive. I just thought including all of that in the code sample was a little over complicated.

Comment: Well,then compare the structs.I know that two closures with equal body and signatures are not the same type.The same must be for functions.

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to compare the functions directly. I don't want to deal with comparing two structs that are both several megabytes in size and require a lot of initialization work.

Comment: You can try adding a sprecific return to each function and then compare them as I told.Or making a procedural macro attribute that takes the function as items and implements a method that return their source code in string form.The way you see more optimal.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns of that functions in Rust actually do implement `PartialEq` as long as there is not a lifetime attached, and as long as the function takes less than 10 arguments. This restriction is because each form of function signature has to have the traits implemented directly, because the compiler considers all of them to be completely unrelated types.

The functions I was returning took a mutable reference to a struct, which implicitly gives the function a lifetime, so they no longer had a type signature which implemented `PartialEq`. All that rust really does internally to compare function equality though is cast both of them to pointers and then compare, so we can actually just do the same thing.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn picks_correct_function() {
        assert_eq!(
            pick_a_function(1) as usize,
            add as usize
        );
    }
}
```