# How to compare a function stored in a struct to what it's referencing

Tags: rust, function-pointers

Is there any way to compare `bar.foo` to `foo`?

```
fn foo() {

}

struct Bar {
    foo: &'static (dyn Fn()),
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar { foo: &foo };

    if bar.foo == foo {
        println!("equal");
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=feda866ad2102983ae3d51d34d044320))

This gives the error: `` binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `&dyn std::ops::Fn() ``

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830617/comparing-functions-for-equality-in-rust) cannot be applied to my case. It proposes trying to check the return value or cast the functions to a `usize`. `foo` doesn't return anything and `bar.foo` cannot be cast to a `usize`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing functions for equality in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830617/comparing-functions-for-equality-in-rust)

Comment: @E_net4removesmeta-commentary No because neither answer applies to this case. ```foo``` doesn't return and ```bar.foo``` can't be cast to a ```usize```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test function pointer equality by first converting the references to raw pointers: `bar.foo as *const _ == &foo as *const _`.

Note however that this is not very robust. There's a high chance you'll run into a situation where you would expect the pointers to be equal, but they aren't. To quote eddyb from a [reddit post that asked the same thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/98xlh3/how_can_i_compare_two_function_pointers_to_see_if/):

> Note that there are no guarantees about getting the same function pointer twice - you'd need to be within the same crate and codegen unit, when casting the function to a pointer, to have a chance.
>
> Oh and LLVM will happily combine two different functions into one, if they happen to have identical bodies, so watch out for that too.